# how to reference one output from a multi-outputs with different dimension in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

Currently, I have this out put from my model:

`egen = keras.models.Model(egen_input, [classes,x])`

where `x` has `[None, 32, 32, 3]` and `classes` has `[None, 2]` as their dimension. How can I reference only part of the output in a custom loss function?

for example,

```
def customLoss():
  def loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    return keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred[0])

return loss
```

currently the above loss function returns me error on mismatched dimension,yet if i just use `y_pred`, it does not return error...very confused here

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only `classes`, which is the first output, to calculate the loss, then you can set the `loss_weights` option (https://keras.io/models/model/) when compiling.

```
model.compile(...., loss_weights=[1.0, 0.0])
```

Note also that loss is computed for each output separately, then averaged (with equal weight at default) across outputs to obtain a single loss metric.  So `y_pred[0]` does not mean `classes`, but the first element of `classes` and `x`.

EDITS.

> if it's the first element of classes and x, what would be the shape of y_pred[0] ? bit confused here

Both! Keras computes the loss for `classes` and `x` separately, then take the (weighted) average.  So, if the loss function is defined as `return keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred[0])` as in the question, keras tries to calculate the loss with `classes_true` vs `class_pred[0]`, and with `x_true` vs `x_pred[0]`, which raises shape mismatch error.

Comment: if it's the first element of classes and x, what would be the shape of y_pred[0] ? bit confused here